# Should MSMQ outgoing queue be empty on successful sending of message?

Tags: msmq

This would be a pretty easy question to answer.
I have inherited a project involving MSMQ. The program sends confirmation messages to an external message sender. So my question is that when my program sends out the confirmation MSMQ Message to the sender, if the message has been sent successfully, then the Outgoing Queue would be empty correct?
My knowledge is that if there are any messages accumulated in the Outgoing Queue, then they have not been sent for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

> My knowledge is that if there are any messages accumulated in the
>   Outgoing Queue, then they have not been sent for whatever reason.

No, it means that either:

1 - a message hasn't been sent at all (usually outgoing queue status is "waiting to connect")

or

2 - a message has been sent but no acknowledgement has been received from destination (usually outgoing queue status is "connected")

So, if you are seeing messages delivered in the destination queue then it is (2).
Check the outgoing queues on the destination machine - there should be an outgoing queue pointing back to the original machine that contains the undelivered acknowledgments.